# Difference between the following codes in array Reversal in C

Tags: arrays, c

I came across a different style of accessing indexes of array on a discussion forum. The following is the pre given code to which we had to write array reversal logic.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num, *arr, i;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    arr = (int*) malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        scanf("%d", arr + i);
    }

    
   
    
    /* Write the logic to reverse the array. */

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("%d ", *(arr + i));
    return 0;
}
```

### My logic to reverse array

```
/* Write the logic to reverse the array. */
for(i = 0; i < num/2; i++) {
        int  temp;
        temp=arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[num-(i+1)];
        arr[num-(i+1)]=temp;
        }
```

### Logic I saw in discussion section and was not able to quite understand

```
/* Write the logic to reverse the array. */
    int temp;
    for (i = 0; i < num / 2; i++) {
        temp = (int) *(arr + num - i - 1);
        *(arr + num - i - 1) = *(arr + i);
        *(arr + i) = temp;
    }
```

**Could you please explain the second logic and how is it better than my logic.

Comment: it is the same as your approach only instead of indexing the array in the usual sense it treats it as pointer and indexes the positions as offests from this pointer. Apart from that the logic is exactly the same'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: `arr[i]` is equal to `*(arr + i)`

so `arr[num-i-1]` is equal to `*(arr + num - i - 1)`

your code is almost the same as the second

Answer (score 2):

> how is it better than my logic

From "logical" point of view, it's equal.

> Could you please explain the second logic

A statement `a[b]` is exactly equivalent to `*(a + b)`. The second code snippet is exactly equivalent:

```
int temp;
for (i = 0; i < num / 2; i++) {
    temp = (int)arr[num - i - 1];
    arr[num - i - 1] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = temp;
}
```

The superflous cast to `int` is just doing nothing and can be removed. Because `- i - 1` is eqaul to: `- (i-1)`, we can:

```
int temp;
for (i = 0; i < num / 2; i++) {
    temp = arr[num - (i + 1)];
    arr[num - (i + 1)] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = temp;
}
```

which is just equivalent (except for some corner cases, when overflows would happen).

Then the order of elements used differs. You an switch two elements by doing:

```
int temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

or by

```
int temp = b;
b = a;
a = temp;
```

Which is exactly equivalent, just your codes starts switching with `arr[i]` and the code presented starts switching with `arr[num - (i + 1)]`.

Comment: So basically I can use indices as I used instead of accessing the array with pointers. that will also do the job, right? I am not very good at understanding the concept of pointers as of now. Thank you so much for such a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid indexes:

```
int *reverse(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    int *end, *saved = arr;
    if(arr && size > 1)
    {
        end = arr + size - 1;
        while(end > arr)
        {
            int tmp = *arr;
            *arr++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
    return saved;
}
```

Always use functions for this kind of tasks.